# Auto image slider that starts from the beginning infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

[image]

As the sketch above shows, I need a slider gallery where four images slide to left one by one automatically. As the fourth image leaves, the first one follows as if it were the fifth.

How can I achieve this goal, without any plugins, just CSS and a little bit JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexislider.js"></script>

<div id="slider">
    <div id="imageloader" style="display: none;">
        <img src="images/header-logos_04.jpg" />
    </div>
    <img src="images/header-logos_04.jpg" />
    <img src="images/header-logos_05.jpg" />
    <img src="images/header-logos_02.jpg"  />
    <img src="images/header-logos_03.jpg"  />
    <img src="images/header-logos_02.jpg "  />
    <img src="images/header-logos_03.jpg" />

 </div>
```

jquery.flexislider.js

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
pic = jQuery("#slider").children("img");
numImgs = pic.length;
arrLeft = new Array(numImgs);

for (i=0;i<numImgs;i++){

    totalWidth=0;
    for(n=0;n<i;n++){
        totalWidth += jQuery(pic[n]).width();
    }

    arrLeft[i] = totalWidth;
    jQuery(pic[i]).css("left",totalWidth);
}

myInterval = setInterval("flexiScroll()",speed);
jQuery('#imageloader').hide();
jQuery(pic).show(); 
});

function flexiScroll(){

for (i=0;i<numImgs;i++){
    arrLeft[i] -= 1;        

    if (arrLeft[i] == -(jQuery(pic[i]).width())){   
        totalWidth = 0; 
        for (n=0;n<numImgs;n++){
            if (n!=i){  
                totalWidth += jQuery(pic[n]).width();
            }           
        }   
        arrLeft[i] =  totalWidth;   
    }                   
    jQuery(pic[i]).css("left",arrLeft[i]);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to insert the images one at a time into HTML and have them take on the banner functionality, the tricky part that we couldn't repeat anything in HTML so [keyframe](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) should be used to animate it,

Check that [article](http://designshack.net/articles/css/infinitephotobanner/) for the complete solution, and that [live demo](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/photobanner/index.html)

Comment: This is one smooth scrolling, not sliding one by one.